# How to install Sardu in Linux?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

What is the proper way to install Sardu in Ubuntu?

I downloaded the gz archive from here: https://www.sarducd.it/downloads, uncompressed it, made a chmod and tried to run the Sardu_3 script, but I'm probably still too noob, as it didn't work.

I'm from a live session with Ubuntu ([Multisystem](https://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/) flavour).
All the [dependencies](https://www.sarducd.it/forum/sardu-linux-version/sardu-multiboot-creator-3-final-for-gnu-linux-t1862.html) are okay.

The file "Sardu_3" (the executable it seems).

"Allow to execute" appears as properly checked.

-> "Run" with the mouse, makes nothing.
-> Running in the terminal from the repertory where it has been downloaded, give "**cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**".

I've checked the error, and it seems that the file is not made for my architecture,
but the problem is that it's the only file provided by the author: sarducd.it/downloads

Should I install something like Ubuntu Server for ARM to be able to run it?

I get also some troubles for installing multibootUSB from the deb package Running it with the package manager makes nothihng, and running it with "`dpkg -i python3-multibootusb_9.2.0-1_all.deb`" from its downloading repertory.

Gives `erreur de traitement de l'archive python3-multibootusb_9.2.0-1_all.deb (--install) :  ne peut pas accéder à l'archive` (can't install the archive): `Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type` (no file or folder of this type) `Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution.`

Comment: Instead of saying "it did not work", you could let us know what actually happened (e.g. by copying and pasting the verbatim error messages, if any, into your question). That would allow us to give more useful answers (actually, allow us to give _any_ answer).

Comment: The file "Sardu_3", the executable it seems. "Allow to execute" appears as properly checked. "Run" with the mouse, makes nothing. Running in the terminal from the repertory where it has been downloaded, give "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error". I've checked the error, and it seems that the file is not made for my architecture, but the problem is that it's the only file provided by the author: https://www.sarducd.it/downloads Should I install something like Ubuntu Server for ARM to be able to run it?

Comment: I'll paste this in the question, as my question was really incomplete.

Comment: If the executable packaged with the `.deb` file is not an ARM executable and you are using an ARM machine, then you will unlikely be able to use that `.deb` package. If the developer provides an ARM executable for Linux, then that executable will more likely work on your system. Not being familiar with the peculiarities of Linux nor the software, I'm avoiding posting this as an answer.

Comment: The problem is that it's the only package provided by the author, with no mention of the incompatible distros or architectures, that's weird.

Comment: `sardu_3.4.0-linux.tar.gz` is a 64bits "amd64" package. With an x86_64  / amd64 OS, the command `./sardu_3` will open the GUI OK.

Comment: I have a 32 bits system :(